# nlsList() error Error in object[[3L]][[1L]] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to run a series of non-linear regression in R. The models I'm trying to fit describe the progress of a viral population through time at three different temperatures. I'm trying to use the function nlsList() with a groupedData object:

```
surv <- groupedData(LOG10N ~ t | Temp, data.frame(cbind(rbind(surv4, surv22,surv56), 
                                                    Temp=rep(c(4, 22, 56), 
                                                             each=8))))
```

Where LOG10N is the log10 of the population, t is time and Temp the temperature. With the nlstools package I'm trying to fit the mafart model, so i used the mafart model formula to create a self starter:

```
mafart.self <- selfStart(~ LOG10N0-(t/delta)^p, surv,
                     parameters=c('p', 'delta', 'LOG10N0'))
getInitial(LOG10N~mafart.self, data=surv56)
```

When I try to get the initial values I get the following error:

```
Error in object[[3L]][[1L]] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

If I skip the getInitial() step and use the nlsList() function like follows I get the same error:

```
> curve.maf <- nlsList(LOG10N~mafart.self, surv)
Error in model[[3]][[1]] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

I've tried to run the regressions separately with nls2() but the results are totally disappointing, as they return the same values used as starters.